# SSD Spindown Settings

Tags: power-management, ssd, system-settings

I have dual SSDs in my new laptop, but the second SSD isn't used as often.  Does "spin-down" have any affect on SSDs for preserving battery life?  Is there a delay in SSDs in the event that the device is needed again?

Does it actually shut off the device's circuitry (saving power) or does it just put the HDD into a special spun-down mode which wouldn't be implemented on an SSD.

Overall, should I set aggressive "Save Power" settings on the secondary?
Should I do the same for the primary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing spinning in a SSD so there is nothing to spin down. Modern SSDs use only a fraction of a watt so there would be no power consumption savings. The drive must be awake enough to know when to receive commands so the power can't be totally shut down. Maximum power consumption, still a fraction of a watt with the latest drives, is during writes; much less during reads.

This answer is OS independent and applies to Linux, OSX, Windows, whatever. Modern OS releases, since Windows Vista for example while less so for Linux, understand that they are working with a SSD and don't defrag the drive.

Do make sure you are backing up your data because as SSD speeds have increased, their lifespan has decreased (number of times a given bit can be rewritten). If you never use more than 20% of your drive, it might last 50 years. If you fill it to 90%, it could start failing within a year.

Unlike a hard drive, they rarely fail dramatically. The drive can detect when some bits are "wearing out" and switch to some backup areas. Eventually you'll notice the maximum size of the drive decreasing as worn out areas are made unavailable. In large data centers, SSDs are used for their speed and not reliability, they have about the same failure rate as data center quality hard drives.

That said, I have 3 SSDs in my HP Z420 Workstation and really enjoy the performance improvement while saving energy. Have been considering replacing the power supply with a smaller, more energy efficient one except the 6-core Xeon processor does use a fair amount of energy.